# Comparing two xsd files for differences in elements

Tags: xml, xsd, comparison

I am trying to compare two .xsd files to find differences in elements.

For example, "file1.xsd" and "file2.xsd". If **either** of these contained the following:

```
<complexType name="ComplexType1">
<element name="ElementName1" type="int" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
    <annotation>
        <documentation>
            Text here
        </documentation>
    </annotation>
</element>
</complexType>
```

and the other one did not, I would want to be notified (for example just having the names of elements which are not in both .xsd files listed in a txt file in the form "Complex type, element name").

Furthermore, if "ElementName1" is under "ComplexType1" in file1, but under a different complex type in file2, I would also like this to be included.

Thanks

Comment: There is no function or built-in mechanism to compare XSDs. A (non-trivial) program is required to do what you are asking . . .and I am afraid none here is going to write that from scratch for you...I'd suggest you start writing it and come back with specific questions (if any)

Answer (score 2):

You really don't want to do this by hand and for sure nobody is going to write such a complex method from scratch, it doesn't fit the [Q&A nature of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, several tools exist that can do this for you:

- oXygen has an [XML diffing feature](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/xml_diff_and_merge.html)
- Stylus Studio has an [XML diffing feature](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xml-diff.html) and can map [XSD to XSD](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsd-mapping.html), which allows side-by-side comparison in a graphical way
- Altova probably has similar features, but I didn't try them
- Liquid XML has a [video tutorial on their diffing feature](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Liquid-Products/LearnAbout/Liquid-Xml-Studio/XmlDiff.aspx).
- [DeltaXML](https://www.deltaxml.com/)
- many more exist, also freeware and open source

If you want to this automatically, [as MiMo said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522975/comparing-two-xsd-files-for-differences-in-elements#comment52906603_32522975), start writing whatever you need and when stuck at some point, ask a question an a specific subject.